# Downvoting questions and answers

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

It appears that some are upset about the reputation people earn. I have received several downvotes without any feedback, so I don't think there is a problem with my answer. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/777665/what-do-embedded-systems-run/777674#777674.) has received 2 downvotes. Is it possible for a meta user to suspend an account for someone that has posted many downvotes?

Comment: Voting is anonymous. How do you know who's downvoted you "many" times? What's the benchmark for "many"?

Comment: Sorry, but what does *"Is it possible for a meta user to suspend an account for someone that has posted many downvotes votes?"* mean? What is a meta user? Downvoted votes?

Comment: It's true I don't know who down-voted my answer, but the system does (how else do they aware badges). Considering the number of down-votes I received (90% of my answers) I would say that any person abusing the reputation would have over 100 down-votes.

Comment: I have over a 2k downvotes - downvotes are essential for site like [su] to maintain quality. By your logic most of top voters would have to be suspended. That's just absurd. (also note: I have over 11k upvotes, and your profile says you've voted a grand total of 2 times).

Comment: @slhck Someone edited my question which is why "downvoted votes" appeared.

Comment: @Sathya You have been on the site over 4 years. I have been on the site less than 6 months and to have 90% of my answers down voted is not reasonable.

Comment: @LDC3 you have downvotes on 4 posts. Saying you have 90% of your 32 answers downvoted is absurd. If indeed that's the case then you should look at improving your answers, not petition for suspension of downvoters

Comment: If you did have 90% of your answers downvoted(which is false) then you'd have [been blocked from answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: I see this happening more an more often. People moaning about getting couple of downvotes. Its not a game where you are trying to get a best score. It is a community where people are trying to help each other by answering questions and choosing best answers. Every time I get a downvote, I carefully read through my post, and try to learn from my mistakes. After all, it is about choosing the best answer for the question. Also, one downvote takes away just 2 rep points so why bother about it in the first place?

Comment: @smc I complained because I saw a lot of down votes recently and it seems it was on many of my answers (which I have found out is not as many as I thought, I'm sorry that I overreacted). Except here, I have not yet seen any comments about why a person cast a down vote (it's very annoying). After all, if a person casts a down vote, they should take the time to comment.

Comment: Downvotes on meta means we don't agree with you.  Its obvious in the reason people don't agree with you.  Your complaining about getting downvotes on an answer people believe isn't a good answer and you are here trying to defend said answer instead of just making the answer better.

Comment: @LDC3 Look at this [SE meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting) on downvoting.

Answer (score 8):

Your answer does not explain anything; it's just two sentences. There's more valuable information in the comments to your answer than in the post itself.

By all means, I see no reason it should *not* be downvoted – if only to encourage you to improve it. Just because you didn't receive any feedback doesn't mean your answer is without problems.

Note: The question is too broad anyway, since it would require a much too long answer, covering what embedded systems are, and how they run for every imaginable device. Perhaps it can be more focused.

Comment: The answer is suitable for the original question.

Comment: No, it's not a suitable answer for *any* question. We do require a little more explanation.

Comment: @LDC3 - The original question change by a single word.  Your answer is a comment at best.  We expect more substance with both answers and questsions at Superuser.  We want not only quality questions that lots of people have but also answers that can help anyone with that question.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer is woefully short considering the scope of the question asked and is borderline wrong.

I did not down vote it, but I was very close as it only barely answered the question.

*All* computers can and do run some amount of precompiled code, not just embedded systems. The difference is that higher powered processors with more memory available can support and run larger programs.  Embedded systems can still run multitasking systems such as FreeRTOS and the only real difference these days is the size and scope of the programs that run on each system.

You could have said so much more in your answer and in my opinion there are some borderline off topic questions such as this one that can be saved from closure by great answers, yours was not that answer.